# Having an officer fake a German accent and request a girl...?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

[the source](https://books.google.jo/books?id=pfB9VsrdX4IC&pg=PA150&dq=Having%20an%20officer%20fake%20a%20German%20accent%20and%20request%20for%20the%20night&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiw-bQg5TYAhWEL1AKHSInBX8Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> - Having an officer fake a German accent and request a girl for the night — it was entrapment; what would they think of next?

Could we paraphrase it this way:

[Having an officer fake] [a German accent] and [having an officer a request] [which is a girl] for the night.

Request <sub>noun</sub> = girl

And does “it was entrapment” refer or modify the whole sentence above, mentioned before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Request" does NOT mean girl. "Request a girl for the night" means to request the sexual services of a prostitute.

"Entrapment" in this sentence is being used in accordance with its specialized meaning in American criminal law. It means roughly that the government encouraged the commission of a crime by someone who was unlikely to have done so without that encouragement. It may be a defense to a criminal charge.

The structure of the sentence is commonly heard in American speech: a complex subject is terminated before a complete sentence is formed; there is a pause, and "it" is substituted for the complex subject to form a complete sentence. So the meaning is "An officer pretending to be German and asking for a prostitute is legally entrapping her." It is perfectly good English (though it may not be good legal advice).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why the writer used request instead of requesting as he did with having, and is this part of the sentence “having an officer a German accent...” a dependent clause?

Comment: Having an officer fake ... and [having that officer] request is what the phrase is saying. This omission of words that are expected to be understood is called an "ellipsis."  "To have someone do" means to "order someone to do." In other words, the writer is assuming that the police officer did not do this on his own, but was told to do it by a superior.

Comment: Now i got it. This kind of have is causative. Which looks like get and make.